# asp.net mvc tutorial project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I'm having some trouble getting the code to work from the book "Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework."  I'm on page 96 for those that may have worked through this book before.  When I run the code I get the following:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Invalid object name 'Products'."
  Source=".Net SqlClient Data Provider"
  ErrorCode=-2146232060
  Class=16
  LineNumber=1
  Number=208
  Procedure=""
  Server=".\\SQLEXPRESSADV"
  State=1
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
       at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity>.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at WebUI.Controllers.ProductsController.List() in C:\Documents and Settings\adamsb1\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\StoreSolution\WebUI\Controllers\ProductsController.cs:line 28
       at lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__7()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:
```

All my code builds fine with no errors and it appears to be identical to the book.  However, I can't get this to work.  I'm an old school asp guy so this is all new to me.

Answer (score 4):

The error is in the database. Either the connection string you have provided points to the wrong database, or the database you are using is missing the table "Products", which is expected to be there.

Since it looks like you are using an SQLExpress database, I might guess that you haven't setup the tutorials database - the program is trying to read from whatever SQLExpress database you already have setup on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

David you pointed me in the right direction...thanks!

I swapped out the following on my connection string:

OLD:
Server=.\SQLEXPRESSADV.SportsStore;Trusted_Connection=yes;"

For the one below and it works now.

NEW:
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESSADV;Initial Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False